# Why is my find clause not working?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have three models: Company, Office, CompanyPersonTask. The Company model has many Office and has many CompanyPersonTask.

So, why is this code:

```
public function getCompaniesByRegion($region){
    $options['conditions'] = array("UPPER(Office.region) LIKE UPPER('".$region."%')");
    return $this->find('all', $options);   
}
```

resulting in the following error ?

> "Unknown column 'Office.region' in 'where clause'"

The `region` column **is** present in the `offices` table.

Comment: Could it be that the table is in fact called `offices`, like you wrote in your last sentence?

Comment: Do you need a join with office?

Comment: The table is called offices, in plural form, like any other db table...
Like specified by name convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As if you have specified the proper association-ship between `Company` with `Office and CompanyPersonTask`. i.e. `Company hasMany Office` and `Company hasMany CompanyPersonTask`.
Then you could write it as:
In your Company Model write:
    public $actAs = array('Containable');

Your method should be:

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
     public $uses = array('Company', 'Office', 'CompanyPersonTask');

     protected function _getCompaniesByRegion($region){
         return $this->Company->find('all', array('contain' => 
                    array('Office' => array('conditions' => array("UPPER(Office.region) LIKE " => "UPPER('".$region."%')")))
                                                 )
                                    );
     }        
}
```

You can call this method into any controller using `$this->_getCompaniesByRegion($region_val);`

Comment: Where do you intend to put that method? I had put it in Company model. In this way the two solutions doesn't work, the first get a non-object call, the second gave me the same error. I have resolved using the first solution removing Company from chain:
return $this->Office->find('all', $options);

Comment: A related problem is: calling find through Office model, I can't access to CompanyPersonTask model, cause it's is related to Company, not office.

Comment: Can you be cleaner? What should I have in Company model and what in AppController (and why in appController?)?

Comment: Nothing changed, the only resulted Model are Office, Company and OfficePersonTask (a sort of CompanyPersonTask related to Office), but I still need CompanyPersonTask.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#using-containable

Comment: You are the man! The last issue: CompanyPersonTask is just a join table (i.e. a series of id), I need the Person information (i.e. first name and last name). Model binding is: CompanyPersonTask belongsTo Person, Person hasMany CompanyPersonTask)